# Why is this simple SQL and PHP thing not working?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

This is the code -

```
if(empty($errors))
{
    mysqli_select_db($connect,"users");
    $i  =  "insert into people (serial,name,price,desc) values ('','$name','$price','$desc')";
    $qs  = mysqli_query($connect,$i);

    if($qs)
    {
        echo "Awesome";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "geez";
    }
}
```

it is always displaying geez.

Comment: If `$errors` is not empty then "geez" will not display

Comment: `echo $i`, run it directly in the database, any errors? Also, is the database connection being established? any errors?

Comment: why don't you use or die(mysqli_error())

Comment: While it doesn't answer your question, you should have a look at PHP Data Objects (called PDO in the PHP manual) if you're writing PHP5. Properly used, it effectively prevents first tier SQL injection.

Answer (score 11):

One problem is that `desc` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) so you must use backticks when using it as a column name:

```
INSERT INTO people (serial, name, price, `desc`) VALUES ...
```

Comment: oh yeah..i changed it to descr...and it works...brilliant...thanks.

Comment: it doens't take that much to figure out what desc means

Answer (score 3):

```
echo mysqli_error
```

and you go...................

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc) values